# Por que não tem a parte de análise no app?

Tags: suporte

Na verdade, também tenho dificuldades no site mobile, preciso dar um fallback para a versão completa do site. Sempre tive essa dúvida... Foi que ainda não foi priorizado? Ou por que foi julgado que o ambiente do mobile não favorece a análise?

Comment: Creio que não seja de interesse da SE, ou não seja prioridade, fazer isso. Até a versão mobile do site não tem analise, só mudando para versão desktop. Eu particularmente acho dispensável ter analise na versão mobile, mas talvez opções de formatação seriam mais interessantes, quando to no celular, os unicos recursos que gostaria de ter são as formatações para responder e perguntar, esperar chegar num pc pra formatar é bem ruim.

Comment: @diegofm é uma pena, ainda mais para quem o principal meio de acesso é o celular...